# How to reserve label with np.column_stack

Tags: python, numpy, label

```
taxdummy=pd.get_dummies(data['TAX CLASS AT PRESENT'])
boroughdummy=pd.get_dummies(data['BOROUGH'])
x = np.array(data['LAND SQUARE FEET'])
x1= np.array(data['GROSS SQUARE FEET'])
x2= np.array(data['BLOCK'])
x3= np.array(data['LOT'])
X = np.column_stack((x,x1,x2,x3,boroughdummy,taxdummy))
```

[X array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxslL.png)

I want to reserve origin label `x='LAND SQUARE FEET' x1='GROSS SQUARE FEET'` etc. but not 0,1,2,3...

Comment: You could make a structured array from this data.  The labels then identify fields, not columns.  Otherwise, `numpy` arrays don't use row or column labels.  That's what `pandas` adds.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use numpy `column_stack` method if you want to have original column's labels. You can use pandas `concat` method to concatenate your DataFrames:

```
X = pd.concat(objs=[data[['LAND SQUARE FEET','GROSS SQUARE FEET', 'BLOCK', 'LOT']], 
                    boroughdummy, 
                    taxdummy], axis=1)
```